# How to pass data from Navigation Controller to TabBarController

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uikit, uitabbarcontroller

I'm new to Objective C and I'm currently working on an app that uses both `UITabBarController` and `UINavigationController`.

I've already connected both of them with my TabController being the initial Controller. Now I'm trying to pass a (`NSMutableDictionary`) data from my Navigation controller scene (the 3rd scene from a 3-layer scene navigation controller) to my TabBarController, so I could use that data to share between any of the scenes directly connected to my TabBarController.

I don't know how to start programming for that. Can anyone help me? I just need simple code to show how to pass a data from a navigation controller scene to tabBarController scene and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

I used this code:

```
self.tabBarItem.title = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"Tag1"];
```

For example, I made my app whose tab bar string is send from navigation page.

[image: ss1]

[image: ss2]

Comment: I want to send my NSMutableDictionary data from my UINavigationController to my UITabBarController. I used this code to send my data from an NSMutableDictionary from one of my scene to the parentViewController of my Navigation Controller:((restoNavigationController *)self.parentViewController).navOrderList = orderList;
--> navOrderList is a property from parentViewController of my navigationController

Comment: When I tried to pass the data from my Navigation's parentViewController to my TabBar's parentViewController, my app always crash. Can you please help me? Sorry for being dumb here.

Comment: Here's the structure of my app:                          UITabBarController
        |
        |____ UINavigationController1-->VC1-->VC2-->VC3
        |               
        |         
        |               
        |____ ViewController2
        |               
        |          
        |
        |____ ViewController3

Comment: Here's the structure of my app:                          UITabBarController
        |
        |____ UINavigationController1-->VC1-->VC2-->VC3
        |               
        |         
        |               
        |____ ViewController2
        |               
        |          
        |
        |____ ViewController3                                               I want to pass my data (NSMUtableDictionary) from VC3 to TabBarController. Can anyone give any suggestions to do that?

Comment: I'm sorry I cannot understand what you want to do. Can you make some image and write the link here?

Comment: Sorry weed for replying too late. I created an image so you can understand what I wanted to do. Here's the link:http://dl.dropbox.com/u/82141372/MyStoryboard%20pic/MyStoryboard.png    Anyone who can help me with this, just go and check the image so you will understand what I mean. Thanks again in advance!!!